# Auto Incrementing file names?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of files like so

> abc.txt 
>   pas.txt
>   tempr.txt

What I would like to do is to append english alphabets to theese file names .. 
the result should look like this

> abc_a.txt 
>   pas_b.txt
>   tempr_c.txt

This process should continue till the last character  (i.e 'z'). if there are more files then the file names would become

> abc_a.txt 
>   pas_b.txt
>   tempr_c.txt
>   .................
>   filename_z.txt
>  
>   anotherfilename_a001.txt

Notice that the counter was again reset to the first character except an integer was attached to it.

This is the code that i have right now. Please note that it is NOT working ..

```
string alphabets= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
filenames.Add("test1.txt");
filenames.Add("newfile.cs");
filenames.Add("test2.txt");
filenames.Add("newfile2.cs");


string currentFileNmae = string.Empty;

foreach(string s in filenames) {
    char usedAlphabet = new char();
    for(int i = 0;i<=alphabets.Length-1;i+=11) {
        usedAlphabet.Dump();
        alphabets[i].Dump();
        if(usedAlphabet != alphabets[i] )
        {
            if(currentFileNmae!= s)  
            {
                string.Format("{0}--{1}",s,alphabets[i]).Dump();
                usedAlphabet = alphabets[i];
                currentFileNmae = s;
            }

        }


        break;

    }

}
```

I  am part of a team that's building a file renamer tool for our internal purposes and hence i need this code. This is part of the our enumertation functionality that we have planned.

Please suggest. 
thanks

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to check whether a file exists? How to build a counter?

Comment: Maybe if you give us the reason why you are doing this in the first place we could offer a better solution.

Comment: Are name collisions a problem or something you are looking forward to? When you try to rename `Foo.txt` and discover there is already a `Foo_j042.txt` what will you do?

Comment: append a number to it.  if there is one copy it will be renamed as Foo_j042_1.txt . If there are multiple copies they will be renamed as such Foo_j042_2.txt and Foo_j042_3.txt  so on , so forth..

Comment: Sounds like the easy solution is to just count: Start with `int Count = 0;` and use `Count % 26` to get the letter value and `Count / 26` for the numeric. If the numeric is `0` then ignore it. When you `try` to rename use a loop that appends your new collision enhancement value until it succeeds (assuming the error is _file already exists_). Then `Count++` as you move to the next file and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: @HABO .. can you please share with me some code ? thanks

Comment: Why do you need alphabets in this? You can use just numbers.

Comment: @Nilesh , like i said this is a business proposition.. not something of my choice..

Comment: Did you really use a string containing the alphabet to get the `i`th letter? Just use `i + 'a'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had no coffee yet, but this should do.

```
List<string> files = new List<string>();


        int charIndex = 0;
        int numericIndex = -1;

        foreach (var file in files.Select(path => new FileInfo(path)))
        {
            // Create new Filename - This may needs some tuning 
            // to really remove only the extension ad the end
            // It doesnt take care of things like
            // file.bmp.bmp.bmp ...
            string newFileName =  String.Format("{0}_{1}{2}.{3}", 
                file.FullName.Replace(file.Extension,String.Empty),
                (char)(charIndex++ + 97), 
                (numericIndex > -1 ? String.Format("{0:D4}", numericIndex) : String.Empty), 
                file.Extension);

            // Rename the File
            file.MoveTo(newFileName);

            // Increment Counters.
            if (charIndex > 25)
            {
                charIndex = 0;
                numericIndex++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Coffee or no Coffee - but this works .. thanks .. and sorry for the late reply.. was on PTO ..

Answer (score 1):

Try starting here:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

string filename = @"C:\Foo\Bar.txt";

for (int count = 0; count < 100; count++)
{
    char letter = (char)((int)'a' + count % 26);
    string numeric = (count / 26) == 0 ? "" : (count / 26).ToString("000");
    Debug.Print(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + "_" + letter + numeric + Path.GetExtension(filename));
}
```

Substitute your own loop to go through the filenames and use `Path` to manipulate the pieces/parts of the names.

The renaming, IIRC, can be handled by `File.Move`. Surround it with a `try`/`catch` to implement the name collision logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
const string directory = @"C:\\wherever";
string[] fiNames = new string[]{ "abc", "pas", "etc",};
char[] alphabet =       "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
int x = 0;
 string ending = "";
for(int i = fiNames.Count()-1; i>=0; i--)
{
  if(x%26==0)
   {
      x=0 
       if( ending=="")
          ending="1";
       else
          ending=(System.Convert.ToInt32(ending)+1).ToString();
    }
  System.IO.File.Move(directory+fiNames[i], fiNames[i]+alphabet[x].ToString()+ending); 
x++;
}
```